# When to Taylor expand in a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, approximation

I've come across a differential equation:

$\dfrac{d\theta}{dx} = f(\theta)$,

whose analytic solution is very complicated, but in this situation it is valid to Taylor expand functions around $\theta = a$. I observe that solving

$\dfrac{d\theta}{dx} = f(a) + f'(a)(\theta - a) + O((\theta - a)^2)$,

where

$f'(\theta) \equiv \dfrac{df}{d\theta}$,

whilst truncating terms of higher order than $1$, should yield

$\theta(x) = A e^{f'(a)x} + a - \dfrac{f(a)}{f'(a)}$.

Yet, if instead one divides through by $f$ and then expands similarily:

$\dfrac{1}{f(\theta)} \dfrac{d\theta}{dx} = 1$

$= \lgroup\dfrac{1}{f(a)} - \dfrac{f'(a)}{f(a)^2} (\theta - a) + O((\theta - a)^2) \rgroup \dfrac{d\theta}{dx}$,

a solution of different nature is obtained:

$\theta(x) = \dfrac{f(a)}{f'(a)} + a \pm \sqrt{\lgroup \dfrac{f(a)}{f'(a)} + a \rgroup^2 - \dfrac{2 f(a)^2}{f'(a)} (x + c)}$.

My question is how can these two seemingly different solutions be consolidated? And which, if either, is more valid?

Edit: For those wondering why I expressed the differential equation in this particular form, $\theta(x)$ is a physical variable dependent on its position in space (and so one would intuitively view its behaviour in this way), and $\dfrac{d\theta}{dx}$ was obtained from:

$\dfrac{d^{2}\theta}{dx^2} = g(\theta)$.

Comment: Hard to say. In general I can say that you have to be very careful with the approximation you are allowed to make. For example if $f(\theta) = \sin\theta$ around $\theta=0$ we can easily expand $\sin\theta \approx \theta$ but we are not allowed to expand $\frac{1}{f(\theta)}$. If we assume you are allowed to expand both functions then I suspect that if you in the end expand the $e^{f'(a)x}$ and $\sqrt{\ldots}$ correctly (using the same approximations used to expand $f$) you will get similar results within the region where your approximations are valid.

Answer (score 0):

The right thing to do is expand the whole differential equation around $x=x_0$, $\theta = \theta(x_0)$.
If $\theta(x) = a_0 + a_1 (x-x_0) + a_2 (x-x_0)^2 + \ldots$
and $f(y) = c_0 + c_1 (y-a_0) + c_2 (y-a_0)^2 + \ldots$ 
then the DE says

$$ a_1 + 2 a_2 (x - x_0) + 3 a_3 (x - x_0)^2 + \ldots 
= c_0 + c_1 (a_1 (x - x_0) + a_2 (x - x_0)^2 + \ldots) + c_2 a_1^2 (x - x_0)^2 + \ldots $$

so that

$$ \eqalign{a_1 &= c_0 \cr
            a_2 &= c_1 a_1/2 = c_0 c_1/2 \cr
            a_3 &= (c_1 a_2 + c_2 a_1^2)/3  = c_0 c_1^2/6 + c_0^2 c_2/3\cr}$$
etc.

Comment: But would this be right if I were looking to find $\theta(x)$ for $x \in [0,L]$? For further background info, if it's of any relevance, I obtained $\dfrac{d\theta}{dx}$ from $\dfrac{d^{2}\theta}{dx^2} = g(\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place you should write your differential equation in the form
$${dx\over d\theta}={1\over f(\theta)}\ ,$$
which immediately gives solutions of the form
$$x(\theta)=G(\theta)+C\ .$$
Concerning your "expansion", you cannot hope that truncating it after one or two terms would produce something that is, identically in $x$, equal to the correct solution. Such an expansion up to $O(x^k)$ for some finite $k$ can only give the first few terms of the Taylor expansion of the desired solution $x\mapsto\theta(x)$.

Comment: In the first sentence I essentially said G($\theta$) was very complicated (and I believe is actually unobtainable).

I expressed the differential equation in that particular form because it makes sense in the physical system I'm dealing with.
I was not hoping on finding the correct solution to the original ODE, but to the approximated form. $\theta$ represents an angle and $x$ represents a spatial coordinate, and in the particular region I'm solving the ODE (being second order originally), $\theta$ only deviates slightly from a known angle. Those were the grounds on which 'valid' was claimed.